# Архивация отсортированных данных

Tags: tar

Как сделать, чтобы в tar-архив записывались файлы по какой-нибудь сортировке, по имени, или дате?

Answer (score 1):

Определённый смысл в каком-то случае может быть. Я думаю, файлы обрабатываются в порядке их упоминания в аргументах программы, так что отсортируйте этот список заранее.

Answer (score 0):

В вопросе содержится мягко говоря бред.Зачем сортировать данные в архиве.

> Архив — файл, содержащий в себе информацию из одного или нескольких, иногда сжатых (без потерь), других файлов. Является результатом работы программы-архиватора.

Если нужно условие то это одно,а вот сортировка - это мягко говоря - бред.